# sql table row has corresponding row in one of several other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a conceptual question that I'm hoping someone more versed in sql database design can help me with. I have a table in which each row has a corresponding row in one of several other tables. Ie. rows in table 1 have a corresponding row in either table 2, table 3 or table 4 (but NEVER in more than 1... the corresponding row can only be in one of the other tables).

What is the best way to set this structure up. If I put an othertable_id column and a tablename column in table 1, I can guarantee that there is only 1 corresponding row in the other tables, but it seems like a really inflexible messy solution. On the other hand if I put just a table1_id column in table2, table3, and table4, it seems like I will need to run 3 different queries each time I want to find the row that corresponds to a row in table1, AND it seems like I cannot guarantee there only being one entry in any of the three tables for my row in table1.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like what you really need are PostgreSQL inherited tables...

Comment: you should learn referential integrity...

Comment: This sounds like a rather unusual setup. Can you give us a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? You might not need this many tables.

Comment: With option 1, you still can't guarantee that you have only one corresponding row in the other tables, since they do not have any RI.  You could still end up with a bunch of logically orphaned records.

Comment: The MS EF articles on [TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx), [TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx), and [TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx), might be worth reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the second solution, and use a trigger to ensure no more than one related row exists.

The query would look like:

```
select *
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
left outer join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_id
left outer join table4 t4 on t1.id = t4.table1_id
```

If there was a common column among the tables you wanted, e.g., `value`, you could get it like this:

```
select t1.*,
    coalesce(t2.value, t3.value, t4.value) as value
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
left outer join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_id
left outer join table4 t4 on t1.id = t4.table1_id
```

Comment: +1. This is a good combo of relationally correct and straightforward to implement if a different design cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I do not see what is messy with a composite key that sets up your relation to the sub tables. If this is what your logical model works don't try to be too clever and confuse anyone trying to figure out the dependencies.

Working over problems is significantly easier with an example, maybe the following works:

```
A college contains students, professors, and assistants. 
It needs to keep track of each individual's name and address. 
In addition it holds :
    for students, their GPA
    for professors, their office address
    for assistants, their professor
```

I'd work up a model similar to the following:

```
person { person_id, name, address }
student { person_id, gpa }
professor { person_id, office_address }
assistant { person_id, professor_id }
```

When I go to implement this I most likely would end up with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id, type, name, address,
    PK (person_id)
)

CREATE TABLE student (
    person_id, gpa,
    PK(person_id),
    FK(person_id to person.person_id),
    CK(person.type = 'student')
)
```